# tablegateway in Zend3 vs Model in Zend1

Tags: zend-db, zend-framework3, zend-framework-mvc

In the last years I developed a few projects in ZF1.x. Now I started a new one and used ZF3 the first time. I found some very good improvements, but I'm a bit lost with the database models.

What is the real benefit of the tablegateway design pattern? In Zend1 I found it quite easy to join several tables in my model class, now I habe the gateway, an exchange array and in my Module.php I have something like this:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
            'factories' => [
                    Model\ImportTable::class => function($container) {
                        $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\ImportTableGateway::class);
                        return new Model\ImportTable($tableGateway);
                    },
                    Model\ImportTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                        $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Import());
                        return new TableGateway('tablename', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                    },
                    ],
                    ];
}
```

I also have, believing the tutorial, to fill in all my tablecolumns manually, hm seems quite static. That's the first issue.

The second one: I have trouble to decide where to join several tables. Here is a small and easy example, my tables are much more complex:

author 1 --> n books

The topic is books, but I need also the author table to show the name of course, nobody wants to see just the foreign key. What is state of the art? Where should I place my sql with the join statement, how to implement in the pattern, what about the Module.php?

So I have more or less 3 files which some information to the used table. What would be the best way and place to define joins? Of course I could code the join in my controller, but that is kind of no go in a MVC-application, isn't it?

What about skipping my Interfaceclass? Where to set the filters then? Do I really have to fill in the tablename (ony one) in the factories?

EDIT new ideas:

I fighted with the syntax, but now it works with this:

```
public function Project_Unit(Unit $unit = null){

    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
        ->join('t_unit', 't_project.ProjectID = t_unit.ProjectID',array('UnitID','CI_Number', 'Unitname','Shortcut','Suppliername'));       //, left
    return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

}
```

And immediately I have new questions. I have the same fieldnames in both tables, like description etc. 
How can I add aliasnames in this statement.

And in my view, how can I add something like groups, this is what I just have

```
 <?php 

foreach ($imports as $import) : 
var_dump(get_object_vars($import));?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($import->Projectname) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($import->Shortcut) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($import->CI_Number) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($import->Description) ?></td>
     <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($import->Component_Class) ?></td>
```

It is a snippet, and the vardump was just to check which fields I already have. So how can I group the view? I need something like

each project
    each unit of the projectgroup

Is there some elegant possibility or do I need just another loop and do the fitting via css?

Comment: I personally use an ORM that manages my SQL via abstraction. If you don't want to use one, you could take a look at this thread: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-one-many-to-many-relationships-tp4659910p4660095.html

Comment: The code from Zend's tutorials is imho low quality, this is probably the result of them writing the shortest code examples they could make (and keep the tutorials shorter). Examples of this are the closures instead of factory classes and using Module.php instead of config files (closures aren't cacheable).

Comment: yes thats right, I' a bit further now, I will add it in the post